# What is the recommended method to detect if jQuery UI .position() supports the `offset` option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This feature is removed in jQuery UI 1.10 :

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-offset-option-merged-into-my-and-at

How do I check for the new syntax using feature detection (instead of checking for the jQuery UI version number >= 1.10)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to create a working example right now. But if it is required i'll hand in later.

The idea would be to create two elements and using `.position` on it, with the new syntax on it (probably you need to wrap it in a `try` `catch` block). If an exception is thrown it is most likely that it is not supported. If no exception is thrown you can check if the element has the expected position, if yes the new syntax is supported, if not then it is the old one. and you could do an additional check again the old syntax.

After the Test you will remove the elements.

I hope the explanation is clear, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, it's clear enough, thank you. I was hoping for a one-liner like testing for $.ui.somewhat, so I wait a few days, before I finally accept this.

Comment: Ok, I finally went with another solution, but will 'accept' your answer if you post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that jQuery UI 1.10 removes a lot of other features (flagged as deprecated in 1.9, http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/), I finally decided to go with version checking instead of - possibly expensive - feature detection:

```
var SUPPORTS = {
    // http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-offset-option-merged-into-my-and-at
    positionMyOffset: isVersionAtLeast($.ui.version, 1, 9),
    ...
};
```

Using this compare function: http://jsfiddle.net/mar10/FjSAN/

This is not an answer to my original question, so I don't flag it 'accepted'.